# Integration bounds in triple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm having some troubles when I have to find the integral bounds in triple integrals. I'll take this example and write my attempt:

$$\iiint_\Omega{dxdydz}$$

Where $\Omega=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1, x^2-x+y^2\leq0\}$

Using cylindrical coordinates we have that

$$\iiint_\Omega{dxdydz}=\iiint_Drdrd\theta dz$$

Where $D=\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : r^2+z^2\leq1, r^2-r\cos\theta\leq0,r\geq0,\theta\in[0,2\pi)\}$

From $r^2-r\cos\theta\leq0$ we found that $\theta\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and that $r\in\left[0,\cos\theta\right]$;

From $r^2+z^2\leq1$ we found that $z\in\left[-\sqrt{1-r^2},\sqrt{1-r^2}\right]$

Here comes the doubt: why is incorrect to find $r$ from $r^2+z^2\leq1$ writing $0\leq r\leq\sqrt{1-z^2}$ and then, from $\sqrt{1-z^2}$, say that $z\in\left[-1,1\right]$? I've tried and I got another result.

Can someone please explain me how the choose of variables gives the right integration bounds? Thanks to you all.

Comment: Where in the second case did you use $r^2-r\cos\theta\le 0$?

Comment: @Andrei You're right, I should have said that $r\leq\cos\theta$ too. But then another trouble comes in: I have now two conditions on $r$, should I take (for $r$) the minimum of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ and $\cos\theta$?

Comment: Yes. You need to satisfy both. You should then get the same result as in the first case

Comment: @Andrei Thank you! So the second solution isn't incorrect, is just probably way heavier to calculate?

Comment: Correct. Also, not that it matters in this case, note that $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, so $\theta$ cannot be less than $0$, and will be instead from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$. Or change your original $D$, to have $\theta\in [-\pi,\pi)$

Comment: Thanks again. So, to clarify definitely, this approach is correct but, if I choose it, apart some rare cases I will encounter insane harder calculations. Furthermore, in this case I should split the integral in the sum of two integrals, if we suppose $$\cos\theta\leq\sqrt{1-z^2}$$ for $z\leq z_0$, one with $z$ from $z$ to $z_0$ with $r$ from $0$ to $\cos\theta$ plus one with $z$ from $z_0$ to $z_1$ with $r$ from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-z^2}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78398/discussion-between-andrei-and-dunkelheit).

Comment: The volume is the intersection of the sphere bounded by $x^2+y^2+z^2<=1$ and the cylinder $(x-1/2)^2+y^2\le 1/4$. The general result is published in https://doi.org/10.1016/0010-4655(90)90184-3 . This is known as Viviani's volume in this particular case where the cylinder radius is half the sphere radius, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212037/volume-of-viviani-s-window